# r-ideals in commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-domain

I'm learning about r-ideals in commutative rings from a journal by Rostam Mohammadian.

*"A proper ideal I in a ring R is called an r-ideals (resp., pr-ideal), if ab is an element in I with ann(a)=`0` implies that b is an element in I for each a,b is an element in R"*

I tried to find some examples for this, but until today.. ideal `0` was the only ideal that fulfill the definition. Do you think there is any example for this ideal?

Comment: @Atticus Stonestrom actually that is not true! Maximal ideals are usually too "big" to be $r$-ideals. Note that in a domain the only $r$-ideal is $0$.  Every maximal ideal of a ring is an $r$-ideal if regular elements of $A$ are units.

Comment: @BadamBaplan oops!! you are of course absolutely right, I was not thinking clearly! what I meant to write was local rings whose maximal ideals consist of all zero-divisors

Comment: @BadamBaplan I'm so sorry because my question is out of context but I'm curious, do you think that the definition can be applied to a non-commutative ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a domain, then the ideal $A\times \{0\}$ in $R=A\times A$ satisfies the definition of r-ideal (I don't know about the definition of pr-ideal because it wasn't stated).

Comment: I will check further about it. Thank you so much, it helps me a lot^^

Comment: A x A is a cartesian product?

Comment: @yash_ Yes, it's the product ring.

Comment: @user239203 may I know the meaning of domain? is it integral domain or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be a ring and $T(A)$ be the total ring of fractions of $A$, i.e. that is $T(A) := S^{-1}A$ with $S$ the multiplicative set of regular elements of $A$.

> **Lemma** $I$ is an $r$-ideal iff $IT(A) \cap A = I$

**Proof** If $IT(A) \cap A =I$ then let $ab \in A$ with $\operatorname{Ann}(a) = 0$, i.e. $a$ is a regular element, then $b = (ab)/a \in IT(A) \cap A = I$ by assumption.  Conversely, suppose that $I$ is an $r$-ideal and let $b \in IT(A) \cap A$.  We aim to show $b \in I$.  Since $b \in IT(A)$ we can write $b = \sum a_i/r_i$, with each $r_i$ a regular element.   Letting $r = \prod r_i$ it is clear that $rb \in I$, $r, b \in A$.  By the definition of an $r$-ideal, $b \in I$ as desired.  $\square$

This is a helpful reformulation because it is very common that a ring (with zero divisors) has non-zero ideals $I$ such that $IB \cap A = I$ for every ring extension $A \subseteq B$.

Indeed, if $I$ is, for example, a *[pure ideal](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04PQ)* or a *[minimal prime ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_prime_ideal#:%7E:text=A%20prime%20ideal%20P%20is,ideal%20over%20the%20zero%20ideal.)*, then $I B \cap A = I$ for every extension of rings $A \subseteq B$, so a fortiori pure ideals and minimal primes are $r$-ideals.

Additionally this shows that if $A = T(A)$, i.e. the non-units of $A$ are zero divisors, then every ideal of $A$ is an $r$-ideal.

Comment: omg thank you so much, it helps a lot to understanding the concept.